# Find and copy values between workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am trying to automate the task of finding the part number in another workbook (a workbook containing just over 100 sheets) and copying the data into the working sheet.

[image][image]

I have two excel sheets containing data, of which there is a uniquely  identifying part number, (Highlighted cells in image 2) Column "C" image 2 has a corresponding and matching part number in Column "F" image 1. (Though I do not know which sheet the information is on)

I need to loop through Column C, selecting each part number, and application.Find each one in the other workbook, and returning the row where each part number appears.

I currently have:

```
Sub Findvalue()
'
' Findvalue Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+o
'

b = 6 
c = 1
Set Start = "C" & b

While c < 250
    Range(Start).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("SPARES.xlsm").Activate
    Cells.Find(What:="'Start'", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas,     LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Windows("A696237-08_spare_parts U2D.xlsx").Activate
    Range(Start).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    b = b + 1
End Sub
```

Which is a recorded macro with a few fixes to attempt to automate.

Is there any easier way to accomplish this, than with VBA?

Comment: Tell me one thing,, you want to Copy Part name along with related values from any specific sheet of closed WB or from all 100 Sheets?

Comment: From a specific sheet. Though the exact sheet is unknown. So the value must be found in the document, then copied over to the working document.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) will help you avoid using `Activate` and `Select` in your code, which will help to automate it. I also notice you use `LookAt:=xlPart` which is likely to provide you with false positives. `LookAt:=xlWhole` would be safer. Only looking in the columns with the part numbers will speed things up

Comment: @ThomG,, if Macro need to find the search string (in your case Part name) across Workbook then to get the correct Filter data all sheets must have identical data structure,,, if , your Workbook's sheets has identical structure the confirm through comments then I'll show you how to get filtered  records.